# How can I increase the number of years in SQL and in SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a forecast algorithm

```
WITH CTE_AllIDs AS
(
 SELECT TOP 22 ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
 FROM sys.columns
)
SELECT
  c.ID
 ,OrderMonth  = CASE WHEN r.ID IS NOT NULL
       THEN r.OrderMonth 
       -- elaborate function to get the short month name and year
       ELSE ordermonth + 1
       END
 ,OrderQuantity
 ,Trend
 ,Forecast  = CASE WHEN Trend IS NOT NULL AND c.ID <> (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #Temp_Regression)
        THEN NULL
       -- For the last actual value (September in this example), we want forecast to have the same
       -- value as the trendline (instead of NULL). This prevents a gap in the line charts in SSRS.
       WHEN Trend IS NOT NULL AND c.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #Temp_Regression)
        THEN Trend
       -- If trend is not found, it means we can calculate a forecast.
       -- However, we also need to check if the month for which we calculate the forecast comes after
       -- the actual values. Suppose we don't have values for January, then we don't want to calculate
       -- a forecast for January as well. Only for the last 3 months of the year in this example.
       WHEN Trend IS NULL AND c.ID > (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #Temp_Regression)
        THEN (@slope * (c.ID % 100)) + @intercept



       ELSE NULL
       END
FROM  CTE_AllIDs   c
LEFT JOIN #Temp_Regression r ON c.ID = r.ID;
```

[The results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhRtF.png)

How can I do this in the values of the OrderMoth columns increase by one  the? 2023, 2024, etc.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Else in your Case Statement will always contain Null. Try this.

```
ELSE (Select Max(OrderMonth) From #Temp_Regression) + ((C.ID) -  (Select Max(ID) From #Temp_Regression))
```